# Handling Invitations/user management to a multiplayer turn-based game (mobile)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer, facebook-game-groups

I'm beginning the technical design phase for a multiplayer, turn-based game.

I'm having trouble designing the solution for user management/handling invitations.

From my research, it seems like their is fragmentation on how this is handled today (google play services, facebook, and apple all have their own apis).

I'm reaching out to see how other's might have designed their user management and invitation strategies given the current landscape of what's available.

Ideally, for this app, the flow of interactions would look like this: [Gameplay interactions/flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCGkM.png)
*Note: Player 3 should be the last actor and shouldn't receive a notification until player 2 is done. The reason for this is because P3 wouldn't have any actions to take if P2 hasn't played yet.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating for Android, you can look into the implementation done in [Adding Real-time Multiplayer Support to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer). Handling invitations, as given in the documentation, can be done by letting the player see any pending invitations sent by another player then selecting this option should launch the invitation inbox.